# RuntimeError: "upsample_bilinear2d_channels_last" not implemented for 'Long' after converting np array to list

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, detectron

I am trying to send image data across modules.

The following works fine:

```
def process_image(pdf_path, page_dimensions):
  pdf_path = get_pdf(pdf_path, False)
  pdf_name = os.path.basename(pdf_path)
  with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
    conversion_time = time.time()
    chart_images = convert_from_path(
          pdf_path=pdf_path,
          dpi=300,
          fmt="jpg",
          output_file=os.path.basename(str(pdf_path)).split(".")[0],
          output_folder=path,
          use_pdftocairo=False,
          paths_only=True,
          thread_count=8,
      )
    pg_dim, pg_image_path = page_dimensions[0], chart_images[0]
    pg_image = cv2.imread(pg_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    pg_image = cv2.resize(pg_image, (pg_dim[1], pg_dim[2]))
  return pg_image
```

The result of this function (`pg_image`) works fine when taken as input to my Detectron2 model.

However, when I send `pg_image.tolist()` and convert back to np array on receiving (`np.array(pg_image)`) and send it to my Detectron2 model, I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: "upsample_bilinear2d_channels_last" not implemented for 'Long'
```

**So, if converting the np array to a list and converting back changing the data?**

Comment: What's the dtype of the new array?

Comment: @hpaulj `int64` when the conversion is being done.  Else, `uint8 `

Comment: How about the array that works?  We need to determine what's different between the case that works and the one that doesn't.  With numpy arrays that means checking dtype and shape.

Comment: @hpaulj The one that works is `uint8`. The one that don't work (post conversion) is `int64`

Comment: @Dawny33 Were you able to find a solution for this? Ran into this issue myself.

Comment: @AshwinNair Didn't work. So, I decided to sent the img to my API as a bytestream instead